# How to deal with an array of dyanically changed size in a foor loop

Tags: python, matlab

In my codes, there is one matrix that is to dynamically increase in size. The pseudo codes in Matlab are as follows:

```
cnt = 0
for ii = 1:M
    for jj  = 1:N
        if (condition satisfied)
           cnt = cnt + 1
           A(cnt, :, :) = I # I is a matrix that is created within the loop
        end
    end
 end
```

How to implement this in Python by using NumPy?

Comment: MATLAB matrix are not dynamically resizable. They pretend to be, but MATLAB is creating a new array and copying all the data to the new array each time through a loop. That is why the MATLAB editor will warn you not to resize arrays in loops.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

A = list()
for i in range(M):
    for j in range(N):
        if condition satisfied:
            A.append(I)    # I is a ndarray created within the loop.

A = np.array(A)
```

Comment: A by np.array needs further reshaping to obtain that Matlab equivalent

Comment: @jingweimo I don't think so.

Comment: @TheBlackCat: The code works except that I need do further reshaping the resulting array